# Can a CMS be installed in a central location to be used by multiple sites?

Tags: cms, links

These days I have to develop a lot of websites where each is based on a certain CMS, ie. Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla. Instead of always copying the files of each CMS to my project folder, is it possible to have a kind of lib for each CMS and only link to one of them from within my project folder?

So the following setup:

```
~/lib/
    |---wordpress
    |---drupal
    +---joomla

~/projects/
    |---project1
    |---project2
    .
    .
    .
    +---projectN
```

What I would like to do is create a structure of symbolic links (or something similar) in each `project` folder, so that `http://localhost/projectN` uses all the files of one of the cms located in the `~lib/<nameofcms>/` folder.

I have already created something like this with the following command:

```
ln -Ab ~/lib/wordpress | xargs -n 1 -I {} ln -s ~/lib/wordpress/{} {}
```

from within one of the projects folders. That actually worked, but when I tried to »override« the configuration file (in case of wordpress it is the wp-config.php), by replacing the link with a »real« file, it did not work anymore because this very file could not be found any more.

That happened because PHP resolved the symbolic links and so it was looking for:

```
~/lib/wordpress/wp-config.php
```

instead of:

```
~/projects/projectN/wp-config.php
```

Is it possible to create such a linked project structure that works on my local machine? If so, what do I have to do?

Comment: This question is too broad. It totally depends on the file structure. For some it would work and for other's it wont. E.g. with Typo3 it would work. Furthermore you are not mentioning the operating system etc.

Comment: the operating system is Linux, more precise: Ubuntu 12.04. I am asking this because I want to find out if it is possible in general to create a setup so that the CMS does not notice that is used from somewhere else, so the tweak should happen on the operating systems layer.

Answer (score 3):

At least in WordPress you have the [multisite feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)...

Comment: that is not what I want. I know about that feature. I do not want to have the same files copied over and over again on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you're looking for a generic solution for a multi-site where you do not have to care about how the multi-site feature is implemented in any given CMS. I.e. you are hoping for an answer describing some fancy "scheme" where  you're able to link from a project site to a set of CMS "libraries".

The short answer is: This is not possible.

Every given CMS uses a different file system layout and a different method for locating the configuration/settings file.  You need to place this file *outside* the location it is located in the uni-site configuration to have a multi-site.  Being able to use multiple configuration/settings files with a single core installation is the key to having a working multi-site layout.  Since different CMSes uses different methods for locating the configuration/settings files for the multi-sites, a "generic" solution is not possible.

However, if you can live with having to implement CMS-specific solutions (i.e. a different multi-site "library" for each CMS you're interested in, and a different scheme for linking the project site to this library for each CMS), you can have a multi-site.

Here are pointers to the relevant documention for the three CMSes you mention as examples:

- As already mentiond by *foxtrot* there is the WordPress [multiside feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).
- There is also a [multisite extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/5550) for Joomla.
- Drupal has a built-in [multi-site](http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site) mechanism.

Since setting up a multi-site is not trivial, you need to read the documentation carefully for each CMS you're interesting in using for a multi-site.   As I say initially, there is no "generic" solution for this.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. I want to "link" to an entire CMS from a one folder to another on harddrive. I want to have one folder that includes the files of the CMS and another that uses sysmlinks inside it to "virtually" create the same files.

Comment: I do not know how this is implemented in WordPress of Joomla. However  using a symbolic link to the core configuration in the way you describe is one of the ways you can create a multisite in Drupal 7.

Comment: I am searching for a solution where I do not have to care about how it is implemented in any CMS (who knows what will come next), so just a way to share as many files as possible on a local machine. I would like to make the cms »feel«: »I live in ~/projects/projectN«, while its files origin in ~/lib/<cmsname>

Comment: Making the CMS *appear* to live in ~/projects/projectN, while its files actually resides in ~/lib/<cmsname> is part of what multi-siting is about (the other part is to make management simpler by having just one core configuration to maintain).  However, since each CMS do this slightly differently, there exists no solution where you do not have to care about how it is implemented in the CMS.  If it is this type of solution you're looking for, you need to update your question to make this clear. I've already amended my answer.